# How to execute multiple blocks of code with certain cases in switch statement?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, code-structure

I have a switch statement like this:

```
switch(a) {
    case 0: 
        // do something
        break;
    case 1:
        // do something else
        break;
}
```

What I want to do is execute both blocks of code when `a == 2` for example. I would like to write something like this:

```
switch(a) {
    case 0: 
    case 2:
        // do something
        break;
    case 1:
    case 2:
        // do something else
        break;
}
```

but obviously that doesn't work because the first break statement ends the whole switch statement.

The only way I could come up with was writing helper functions:

```
function case0() {
    // do something
}

function case1() {
    // do something else
}

switch(a) {
    case 0: 
        case0();
        break;
    case 1:
        case1();
        break;
    case 2:
        case0();
        case1();
        break;
}
```

This solution seems a bit verbose and ugly to me. Is there a nicer way to achieve what I want?

Comment: `switch` statements are complicated enough. What you're proposing is a change to how they work on a fundamental level. Why not use a mapping table where you can have links to functions? `{ 2: function() { ... } }` for example.

Comment: Well, the main reason I want to keep it in `switch` is that I have built my project upon `switch` statements and I don't want to rewrite it all into something else just to be able to do what I described.

Comment: What you want and what JavaScript can do are two different things. You want to bend to reality or spend your life fighting it? You're welcome to [petition the ECMAScript group through TC39](https://tc39.github.io/process-document/) if you want. Sometimes the approach we think is best doesn't pan out. Learn, adapt, move on.

Answer (score 2):

In the `switch` statement code is executed starting from the first true condition to the closest `break`. So in your case following construction may work.

```
var a = 2;//1;//0;//-1;
switch(a){
  case 2: //and also one and zero
    console.log('two');
  case 1: //and also zero
    console.log('one');
  case 0: //zero only
    console.log('zero');
    break;
  default: //no matches
    console.log('default');
}
```

Comment: This type of execution is called fall through execution  meaning - as I understand and you put it - that without break statements the switch will find the first true condition and fall through to the closing brace of the switch executing every case on the way down. This type of execution is present in C#, C++, Java, javascript, and a few others I'm sure. VB.net is one language that doesn't stick to the general consensus.

Comment: Although this answer comes very close to solving the problem, it still does not allow case 1 to execute independently.

Answer (score 0):

You asked if there was a *nicer* way to achieve what you wanted...

Well, whether or not my solution qualifies depends on your definition of "nicer", but here it is anyway:

You can make your switch statement like this:

```
switch(a) {
  case 0: 
    caseHandler([0]);
    break;
  case 1:
    caseHandler([1]);
    break;
  case 2:
    caseHandler([0,1]);
    break;
}
```

And pass an array of values to a single helper function that employs another switch:

```
function caseHandler(values) {
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    switch (values[i]) {
      case 0:
        console.log('doing zero stuff');
        break;
      case 1:
        console.log('doing one stuff');
        break;
    }
  }
}
```